# Linux and terminal: How to run a command in a terminal appointment?

Tags: linux, time, terminal

I wanted the following, via shell script in linux terminal:

```
myhour = 15:00
if hour_actual <myhour; then
command
else
echo "message"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a scheduled/daily-like task? If so, look into [cron jobs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/).

If you are talking about a script that runs after a certain amount of time, then simply use the `sleep` command. All you have to do with it is say

```
sleep [Number-Of-Seconds]
```

Comment: I answered this under the premise that 15:00 could be 3:00 PM or it could mean "in 15 hours."

Answer (score 1):

Consider schedule a `cron` job. See [this](http://troy.jdmz.net/cron/).

Answer (score 0):

To annswer your question

```
myhour=15:00
if [ $(date +%H:%M) < $myhour ]; then
  Command
 else
   echo ...
 fi
```

( < performs a lexicographic comparison )